# AVG is taking away control from administrator

Tags: uninstall, avg-antivirus

I installed AVG virus protection and since then
It doesn't let me save certain picture formats and
Doesn't let me copy anything to my desktop. It doesn't
Uninstall either. How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

A few questions:

- Did you get avg from the official site? (www.avg.com)
- What operating system are you using?
- Do you have administrator rights
- Can you revert to a restore point that was made at the beginning of the install?

As for a fix... try that last thing...

Comment: it does sound like a bad copy of avg if you were to ask me...

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Windows, use Windows System Restore, pick a restore date before you installed AVG.

Or download and run the AVG Remover tool [from this page](http://www.avg.com/us-en/download-tools), be sure to pick the correct one for your bit version of Windows, 32bit Windows or 64bit Windows.